# Why does a view have surprised time curve with limit?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, query-performance

I have some conflict views:

First, I create some base views to do the low level filters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE conditions

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view2 AS
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE conditions

...
```

Then, I join them respective. The connection relationship looks like one table to many tables, so I create one view for each table-table connection.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW join1_view1 AS
SELECT * FROM view1 JOIN view2 ON view1.entity_type = 'View2' AND view1.entity_id = view2.id WHERE conditions

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW join1_view2 AS
SELECT * FROM view1 JOIN view3 ON view1.entity_type = 'View3' AND view1.entity_id = view3.id WHERE conditions

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW join2_view1 AS
SELECT * FROM view1 JOIN view4 ON view1.assigned_type = 'View4' AND view1.assigned_id = view4.id WHERE conditions

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW join2_view2 AS
SELECT * FROM view1 JOIN view5 ON view1.assigned_type = 'View5' AND view1.assigned_id = view5.id WHERE conditions

...
```

Then I use Union to combine them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW union1 AS
SELECT * FROM join1_view1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM join1_view2

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW union2 AS
SELECT * FROM join2_view1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM join2_view2
```

That's all good for now. But at next step, I will join these two union views.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW join_union AS
SELECT * FRON union1 INNER JOIN union2 ON union1.id = union2.id
```

Then I found if I set different limits, the query time have a bit different.

No limit:

```
SELECT * FROM join_union
```

takes 4 secs. Limit 100:

```
SELECT * FROM join_union LIMIT 100
```

takes 5 secs. Limit 500 takes 10 secs. LIMIT 1000 takes 16 secs.

It's not finished. After 1000, surprised, LIMIT 2000 takes 1 secs. LIMIT 100, 000 (actually it has total 20, 000 records) takes 3 secs.

The curve looks like:

[image]

And the Maximum time happened at `LIMIT 1325`

I executed EXPLAIN(ANALYSE, BUFFERS) in these cases, and I get these plans:

[SELECT * FROM join_union](https://explain.depesz.com/s/ici2) no limit.

[SELECT * FROM join_union LIMIT 1000](https://explain.depesz.com/s/TH59)

[SELECT * FROM join_union LIMIT 10000](https://explain.depesz.com/s/DMcE)

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur: Postgres' query optimizer is different than Oracle's

Comment: Are you timing this with pgAdmin or something? It's possible that the time indication is misleading you. The software maybe is (virtually) paging the data. Also, the amount of data being transfered costs time.
Can you try with `select count(1)` instead of `select *` ? That rules out the impact of the data transfer.

Comment: @johey This time is calculated by python. I use a for loop and run `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM join_union LIMIT %s', (limit_number, ))` again and again

Comment: Okay, that is very weird then! Are you experiencing the same phenomenon when not querying a view but directly a table? Maybe it's due to the combination of a view and a limit.

Comment: Have you tried if the query gives the same timing result in pgAdmin? You never know that python is doing something weird.

Comment: @johey I didn't find this problem before with tables so I guess it related to view too. I use command line, pgAdmin and Pycharm Database Tools, the results are all the same.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added `EXPLAIN(ANALYSE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM view` with different limits, and it looks similar to my experience. Can you help check them? Thanks so much.